# items of a listview are not being displayed in wpf

Tags: wpf, listview, binding

I am trying to add items to a listview where each item has two textblocks, but for some reason items are not being displayed .Here is my XAML code .

```
<Window x:Class="testapp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="524" Width="856">
<Grid Background="Black">
    <!--<Image Height="44" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="284,0,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="229" Source="/testapp;component/Images/Picture1.png" />-->
    <Grid Height="431" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,55,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="266" Background="Black" Opacity="0">
        <ListView  Height="430" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,1,0,0" x:Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Green" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source}" Foreground="Green" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <!-- <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>-->
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is  my C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace testapp
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<MyItems> items = new List<MyItems>();
        items.Add(new MyItems() { Name = "House Party", Source = " DLNA" });
        items.Add(new MyItems() { Name = "Outdoor Party", Source = " DLNA" });
        listView1.ItemsSource = items;


    }


}

public class MyItems
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Source { get; set; }

}
}
```

Even though i am binding textblocks to name and source it is still not displaying.Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not Displaying because of Opacity Parameter. You have defined

```
Opacity="0"
```

in your xaml

please make it to in range between (0-1)

Old Code

```
<Grid Height="431" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,55,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="266" Background="Black" Opacity="0">
```

Change to (New Code)

```
<Grid Height="431" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,55,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="266" Background="Black">
```

Comment: on doing so grid background color changes to white even background color specified is black.

Comment: as mentioned in answer you need to set  it(opacity) to somewhere between 0-1 and for your stying purpose you need to create appropriate style. As per my understanding above answer serves your requirement, styling can not be handled by opacity parameter